# Is it possible to change any app's icon with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

Is it possible to change the icon of any application on macOS with NodeJS...

I've been searching for a bit but I've been unable to find anything useful.
Much like dragging a .icns file onto the icon in the "Get Info" menu for any app but instead with NodeJS .

Answer (score 2):

You just need to replace the icon file inside the app.

1. Treat the app as a folder, look for the `Info.plist` file in the app inside its `Contents` folder.
2. In the `Info.plist` file (it's an xml file) look for the `CFBundleIconFile` key. It's value is the icon file for the app.
3. Here you have two choices - you can either:

   3a. replace this value with your icon or

   3b. just replace the icon file with your own icon with the same name.

Here's an example of replacing the icon file with another file with the same name:

```
const plist = require('simple-plist');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function (appPath, newIconFile) {
    plist.readFile(path.join(appPath, 'Contents/Info.plist'), (err, data) => {

        const iconName = path.join(appPath, 'Contents/Resources', data.CFBundleIconFile);

        fs.copyFile(newIconFile, iconName, (err) => {
            console.log('icon changed!');
        });
    });
}
```

The `simple-plist` library also supports saving the plist data back to disk so I will leave replacing the `CFBundleIconFile` value as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: How would you easily reset it? I have a few ideas, but there might be some easier methods...

Comment: And would you need to have the .app and .icns in the appPath and newIconFile, since in the plist I remember that they don't mention the filetype... EDIT: You do need the extensions :)

Comment: Filetype is .icns. And the icon needs to be installed inside the app's Contents/Resources folder. If you replace the icon you cannot reset it unless you save the original icon somewhere first. If you add your icon and rename the `CFBundleIconFile` property you can reset it by changing the value back to the original. I don't know how the Finder change back to default so I have no idea how to make this undoable in the Finder.